# WCF Serialization not as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, xml-serialization

I have a c# class like this as a return for my WCF method:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("OutputItem")]
public class MyItem
{
    [XmlElement("ItemName")] 
    public string NodeName { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Fields"), XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Field", Type = typeof(MyItemField))]
    public List<MyItemField> Fields { get; set; }

}
```

My WCF method is as such:

```
public MyItem GetItemXML(string id)
{
   MyItem mi = new MyItem();

   //do some stuff to populate mi

   return mi;   
}
```

I expect the XML output of this to be something like this:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <GetItemXMLResponse xmlns="http://www.here.com/XML/ItemService.xsd">
      <GetItemXMLResult>
        <OutputItem>
           <ItemName>FR</ItemName>
           <Fields>
            ......
           </Fields>
        </OutputItem>
      </GetItemXMLResult>
    </GetItemXMLResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

However, the output that is coming out is as follows - without the `<OutputItem>` directive at the top:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <GetItemXMLResponse xmlns="http://www.here.com/XML/ItemService.xsd">
      <GetItemXMLResult>
           <ItemName>FR</ItemName>
           <Fields>
            ......
           </Fields>
      </GetItemXMLResult>
    </GetItemXMLResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know the exact difference, but when generating code from XSDs or WSDL, it uses 'XmlRootAttribute("InsertYourNodeName")' instead of 'XmlRoot("InsertYourNodeName"). I'm pretty sure one inherits off the other, but you might want to try replacing it with XmlRootAttribute and see if you get something different.

Comment: I think you have to decorate the type with [DataContract]. Also the members with [DataMember], but they appearently get deserialized anyway. Perhaps I confusing the model with the contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// The Model Object

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("OutputItem")]
[DataContractAttribute]
public class MyObject
{
    [XmlElement("ItemName")]
    [DataMemberAttribute] 
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("DummyItems")]
    [XmlArrayItem("DummyItem", typeof(MyItemField))]
    public List<Fields> DummyItem { get; set; }
}



// The Class that implement the contract
[DataContract]
public class ConsumptionService : IAnyContract
{
    public MyObject GetItemXML(string id)
    {
       MyObject mo = new MyObject();
       //do some stuff to populate mi
       MyObject mo;   
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly it all depends on how your [OperationContract] is defined. you may have to use Message Contracts to get your desired behavior. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx